# Uploading video to server in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Iam currently working with windows phone 8.1 application.I got stuck in a portion where uploading video to server using phone camera.I want send the video at every 10s to server while recording..thnks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dispatch timer to save your 10-second video clips(StorageFile) in your app localstorage and send the storagefile to another function that makes the fileupload network calls asynchronously.

Comment: I want to upload the video without stop recording..Is that possible?

Comment: yeah! that's possible. All you have to do is write logic in the timer to stoprecord and then create new storagefile and then start recording into new storagefile. repeat reset the timer. Or better you can trim video into 10second clips.(another solution if there is performance issue).Check this  [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing) works only on windows 10 though.

Comment: IInputstream or byte array content is better for server  video upload?

Comment: video you obviously have to upload in bytes. while recording there are two methods.Go for StartRecordToStreamAsync method.

Comment: Is there any way to increase the speed of server uploading while sending the video...thnks in advance

Comment: No,it depends on the net connection and your server side coding. Apart from that, I am not aware of any other optimizations.